# How to find possible chess figure (Knight) positions by it's current position using JAVA?

Tags: java, chess

i'm trying to solve this exercise. It should take two parameters for coordinates and display possible next positions in relation to the entered position coordinates. Currently i'm able to get the board with entered position, but how to calculate next possible positions for the Knight chess figure? Thanks for any clues / suggestions.
My Main file:

```
package lt.chess;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board board = new Board();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Enter board number: ");
        String digit = scanner.next();

        System.out.print("Enter board letter: ");
        String letter = scanner.next();

        Knight knight = new Knight("Knight");
        board.setFigure(knight, digit, letter);
        board.showFigures();
    }
}
```

Board class:

```
package lt.chess;

public class Board {
    private String letters = "ABCDEFGH";
    private String digits = "12345678";

    private Figure[][] arrayFigure = null;

    public Board() {
        arrayFigure = new Figure[letters.length()][digits.length()];
        createBoard();
    }

    private void createBoard() {
        for (int row = digits.length() - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
            System.out.print(digits.charAt(row));

            for (int x = 0; x < letters.length(); x++) {
                System.out.print("  ");
                if (arrayFigure[row][x] != null)
                    System.out.print("X");
            }

            System.out.println("");
            if (row == 0) {
                System.out.print("   ");

                for (int col = 0; col < letters.length(); col++) {
                    System.out.print(letters.charAt(col) + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setFigure(Knight knight,
                          String digit,
                          String letter) {
        int y = digits.indexOf(digit);
        int x = letters.indexOf(letter);
        arrayFigure[y][x] = knight;
    }

    public void showFigures() {
        createBoard();
    }

}
```

Figure class:

```
package lt.chess;

public class Figure {
    private String[] figureColor = {"Black", "White"};
    private String figureName;

    Figure(String figureName) {
        this.figureName = figureName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.figureName;
    }

}
```

Knight class:

```
package lt.chess;

public class Knight extends Figure {

    Knight(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not saying hard-coding values is a good solution, but there's only maximum 8 different locations a knight can get to.

Comment: I don't get your figureColor field: a figure can only have one color. Also, instead of using Strings, why not use an enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a control for board-edges and used fields to Minh's answer, I would provide a method creating the next possible positions (Points)

```
 private LinkedList<Point> getNextPositions(int x, int y){
    int[] xOffsets = {-2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2};
    int[] yOffsets = {1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1};
    Point nextPosition;
    LinkedList<Point>  = new LinkedList<Point>();
    for(int i = 0; i < xOffsets.length; i++) {
        nextPosition = new Point(x+xOffsets(i),y+yOffsets(i));
        if (isWithinBoardAndFree(nextPosition))
        {
            erg.add(nextPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

To check these points I used a second method:

```
private boolean isWithinBoardAndFree(Point point, Figure[][] board){
    if (point.x >= 0 && point.x >= 0)
    {
    if (board[point.x][point.y] == null)
        {
            return true;    
        }
    }
        return false;
}
```

I am not sure about your exercise, but you might consider releasing a field the knight came from.

Comment: Actually, a position is playable if it is occupied by the adversary.

Comment: Thank you for the example, now things look clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two arrays like this

```
int[] x = {-2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2};
int[] y = {1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1};
```

which are helped you calculate the maximum 8 different locations of your knight base on current location.
After that, whenever you need to calculate the possible knight jump, just loop all over it

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Possible knight location: %d, %d", current_x + x[i], current_y + y[i]);
}
```

Note: you should consider the board edge as well as the location has already got other figure.

Comment: Thank you Minh, your answer helped me to move forward.